# Javascript, outside variable scope in callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, scope

everyone.

I have a problem about the 'callback function - scope of variable',

I wanna use the 'i in for loop' to 'the callback function User_UidSearch',

but I cannot use it.

(I hope the solution don't use the global variable.)

---

```
Task_TidSearchExecution = function(tid, callback) {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM execution WHERE task = '" + tid + "'";
    dbclient.query(sql, function (err, results) {
        if (err || results.length <= 0)
            callback(false);
        else {
            console.log(results.length);
            for (var i = 0 ; i < results.length ; i++) {
                User_UidSearch(results[i].employee, function (user) {
                    console.log(i);
                    // results[i]['email'] = user.email;
                });
            }

            callback(results);
        }
    });
}
```

the "console.log(i);"

Recheck, this is wrong. -> Outputs are "undefined" of all.

undefined is "console.log(result[i]);"

But the "i" is keep '2' console twice, if results.length is 2.

I know becuz the for loop ending then execute the User_UidSearch,

but how can I slove the it "i" is 0 and 1.

Comment: No, it's not. It's defined in outer `function` local scope. But it's used in closure, which needs special logic to work. @Salmon - are you sure `console.log(i)` writes `undefined` and not the value of `results.length`?

Comment: @BOSS I would love to see a fiddle demonstrating that.

Comment: "*Outputs are 'undefined' of all*" doesn't really fit with the snippet provided. `i` should at least be a number, just maybe not the particular values expected. If each log shows the value of `results.length`, then see: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Comment: wrap the user_UidSearch call in a closure, pass in i and results

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin: rigt.my bad i didnt see it through clearly.removed my comment

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, sorry, my fault. I had edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures), rewrite your code as follows:

```
...
(function(id) {
    User_UidSearch(results[id].employee, function (user) {
        console.log(id);
        // results[i]['email'] = user.email;
    });
})(i);
```

I.e. wrap your function to unbind `i`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I follow this way solving.

Comment: You're welcome! Closures are great stuff if you know how to use them right!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem may be solved, but let me still add these points so others know the correct approach.

Firstly, its not a good practice to call an asynchronous function inside a loop. This would lead to unexpected results.

Using closures is fine for some cases, but not this one. Read here for [Practical uses of closures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2728341/1520671).

There are several problems in the approach you've taken,

1. If the results array is too long, there'll be a too many open requests.
2. `callback(results)` will be called before even a single callback of `User_UidSearch` is called.

In your case, you should be using recursive function like this:

```
var len = results.length;
var count = 0;
function my_func() {
    User_UidSearch(results[count].employee, function (user) {
        console.log(count);
        // results[count]['email'] = user.email;

        count += 1;
        if (count < len) {
            my_func();
        } else {
            callback(results);
        }
    });
}
```

Read [this](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html) if interested detailed explaination of different control flows.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I had solved your saying.
But your solution is better than mine, thank you very much :)