# Why does this for / setTimeout() code actually output the numbers from 0 to 9?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, closures, settimeout

A common pitfall with JavaScript closures is [running `setTimeout()` from a `for` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2728374/1269037), and expecting the counter to be passed with different values at each iteration, while in practice it gets assigned the last value before the `setTimeout()` functions execute:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(i)
  }, 100);
}  // => prints "10" 10 times
```

One solution to this is to have an Immediately Invoked Function Expression:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  (function(j) {
    setTimeout(function foo() {
      console.log(j)
    }, 100);
  })(i);  // prints 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Another is to pass an extra [callback argument to `setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout#Callback_arguments) (which doesn't work in IE<9):

```js
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function foo(n) {
    console.log(n)
  }, 100, i);
}
```

But why does the following, simplest, code, produce the same result (`0, 1, 2, ... 9`)?

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  setTimeout(console.log(i), 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

This apparently surprising behavior occurs because the [first parameter to `setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) can be a function as well as a string, the latter being `eval()`-ed as code.

So `setTimeout(console.log(i), 100);` will execute `console.log(i)` right away, which returns `undefined`. Then `setTimeout("", 100)` will be executed, with a [NOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP) call after 100ms (or optimized away by the engine).

Comment: Oops, deleted my answer. I misread yours first, but it's correct.  Might just be worth pointing out that the output the OP is seeing is immediate, while still in the `for` loop itself, and long before the 100ms delay.

Comment: Thanks @jmar777, I'm the OP :) I've included your note in the answer. Happy to delete both our comments if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Just for grins, *another* thing you can do (when you've got `.bind()`) is

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    var i = +this;
    console.log(i)
  }.bind(i), 100);
}
```

A little bit less of a mess than an IIFE.

Comment: Oh Pointy, you should know better. This is not an answer. This is a comment.

Comment: @slebetman posting code in a comment is essentially impossible :)

Answer (score 0):

> why does the following, simplest, code, produce the same result (0, 1,
>   2, ... 9)?
>
> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
>   setTimeout(console.log(i), 100);
> ```

Because it actually doesn't. If you look closely, you will notice that the log messages will not need the tenth of a second before they appear in console. By calling the `console.log(i)` right away, you are only passing the result of the call (`undefined`) to `setTimeout`, which will do *nothing* later. In fact, the code is equivalent to

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  setTimeout(undefined, 100);
}
```

You will notice the difference better if you replace the `100` by `i*500` in all your snippets, so that the log messages should be delayed at an interval of a half second.

Comment: @DanDascalescu: Thanks, feel free to upvote and accept :-) In your answer you say something about strings however, which I'm not sure how it is relevant to the problem.

Comment: I was linking to the [MDN docs on setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout), which explain that the first parameter can be either a function **or a string**, which is `eval()`ed. I believe `setTimeout()` converts the `undefined` returned by `console.log()` to en empty string, thus executing nothing after the timeout (or not even setting a timer).

Comment: Yes, that's what I would expect: If the argument is not a function (nor a string), then *nothing* is happening at all.