# How to pass data by value into a deferred then handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, deferred, pass-by-value

I would like to know how to pass data by value, rather than by reference, into a `then` handler on a jQuery `Deferred` object.

I have the following example code to illustrate my question:

```
var value;
var deferred = new $.Deferred();
var data = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

// add a separate call to the chain for each piece of data
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  value = data[i];
  deferred.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response+':'+value);
  });
}

deferred.resolve("test");
```

The result I want to get:

```
test:A
test:B
test:C
test:D
```

The result I actually get:

```
test:D
test:D
test:D
test:D
```

It seems the value of `value` is evaluated at the time the `then` handler is executed, whereas I want it to be evaluated at the time the `then` handler is queued.

I have a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexbfree/azfthnm9/), hope someone can help?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.. you have to create a closure around it

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    value = data[i];
    deferred.then( function(val) {
        return function(response) {
            console.log(response+':'+val);
        }}(value));
}
```

Comment: While this is the right way to go, you have a syntax error in your code (you're missing an end bracket on your deferred).

Comment: Could you explain this concept a bit? how does this get executed?

Comment: What does malloc'd mean?

Comment: @alexbfree I removed my comment because I feel like another user explained it better here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728278/what-is-a-practical-use-for-a-closure-in-javascript). Check out Andy E's example.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me on the right track here. I think closures are indeed the way to go. I found a nice clear explanation on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/971500)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var value;
var data = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

// add a separate call to the chain for each piece of data
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  value = data[i];
  $.when($.Deferred().resolve("test"), $.Deferred().resolve(value))
  .then(function(response, x) {
      console.log(response + ':' + x);
  });
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w63efkoa/1/)

Comment: I find this one a bit confusing... Why do we resolve the deferred twice?

Comment: @alexbfree you need to resolve each parameter from what I understand about `$.Deferred`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the simplest solution would be to move your `for` loop into the promise callback.

```
deferred.then(function(response) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     value = data[i];
     console.log(response+':'+value);
  }
});
```

If you need to have the loop outside of your promise handling, I would consider not defining the function in a loop and using a curried function instead:

```
function processResponse(val){
   return function(response){
      console.log(response,':',val);
   }
}

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  value = data[i];
  deferred.then(processResponse(value));
}
```

Comment: That works in this simplified example, but in my real world case it's not so feasible. I'm looking for a way to do it but keeping the same nesting structure.

Comment: Thanks for adding that alternative approach. Could you explain the "curried function", and how it works?

Comment: Curried functions utilize a closure to maintain access to the parent function's scope and return a function that makes use of the "curried" data and whatever is passed to the returned function. I think Crockford does a good job of explaining currying in JS here: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/www_svendtofte_com/code/curried_javascript/index.html