# li input checkbox: how to get checked state javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have access to each of the li[i] that returns what you see in the picture. An example would be `li[i].innerText` returns `business`. How can I get the `checked` state of each element?

[image: element iteration]

```js
//loop through li elements in categories to add listeners
  for(var i = 0 ; i < li.length; i++){
    (function(i){
        li[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();

          //disallow repeats
          if(checkedItems.indexOf(li[i].innerText) == -1){
            checkedItems[counter] = li[i].innerText;
            counter++;
            console.log("added");
          }

          console.log(li[i].checked); //undefined
          //remove element if unchecked from array
          if(li[i].checked){
            var index = checkedItems.indexOf(li[i].innerText);
            console.log(li[i].innerText +": " + index);
            checkedItems.splice(index, 1);
            console.log("disabled");
            counter--;
          }
    console.log(checkedItems);
        });
    }(i));

  }
```

Comment: Use `this` instead of `li[i]` within the event handler function and remove your closure. You can then get the state with the `checked` property

Comment: I'm seeing a function in a for loop, is that a good idea? o_O

Comment: @odedta it's a closure - required in this case.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Could you refer me to a place to learn more about this please?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728278/what-is-a-practical-use-for-a-closure-in-javascript)

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem. Just also note that while they aren't technically bad practice, they should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Oh thanks for the info about closure's Rory! So what I did was I removed the closure and replaced all `li[i]`s with `this` inside the for loop. However everything returns as `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the `input` element, which you can do as follows:

```
var input = this.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');
```

... and then you can use `input.checked`:

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for(var i = 0 ; i < li.length; i++){
    li[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      //event.preventDefault();
      var input = this.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');
      console.log(this.textContent.trim(), input.checked);
    });
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
    <span>test</span>
    <input type="checkbox">
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sweet! Got it. Thank you very much. Accepted answer because example.