# calling multiple setInterval() functions in js with a loop

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm new to javascript and I'm having trouble using the setInterval() function properly.

Basically I want to call a function at different given intervals for different parameters both of which I have in lists.

I have a function called myfunction. I have a list called myparam with all of the variables I want to pass this function. And finally I have a list called myfrequency which is the time in millis that I want between each call of myfunction with the parameter given in myparam.  I'm trying something like this but it's not working:

```
for(i=0;i<myparam.length();i++;){
    setInterval(function(){myfunction(myparam[i]);},myfrequency[i]);
    }
```

The result of the above code is that it works only for the last index. myfunction gets called at the correct interval with the correct parameter for ONLY the last value in myparam.

Why does this happen? Is my thinking that setInterval() sets up the calling of a function at an interval incorrect?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728278/what-is-a-practical-use-for-a-closure-in-javascript read the answers, one of them shows your exact problem

Comment: Very common problem. What is happening is that by the time your setInterval fires, the loop is already done so `i` is pointing to the last element

Comment: @david does adding a delay fix this? I tried adding a delay with setTimeout() for each time setInterval is called but now its not working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's because setInterval has a delay which means when the interval runs
the loop is already been finish

To do that just create another function which will start your interval

```
function StartInterval(index, frequency) {
    setInterval(function(){
        myfunction(index);
    },frequency);
}
```

Then inside your loop just call this function and pass something

```
for(i=0;i<myparam.length;i++){
    StartInterval(myparam[i], myfrequency[i])
}
```

```js
   
/** set what value you want **/
var myparam = [10,20,30];
var myfrequency = [1000,2000,3000];


function myfunction(index) {
  console.log(index);
}

function StartInterval(index, frequency) {
  setInterval(function(){
    myfunction(index);
  },frequency);
}

for(i=0;i<myparam.length;i++){
  StartInterval(myparam[i], myfrequency[i])
}
```

Comment: Dah - just beat me to it! Also to note - the original javascript has a few syntax issues. myparam.length is a property, not a function (assuming that myparam is an array), and the last semicolon of the for loop (i++;) is not needed.

The reason this is a problem deals with what is called a "closure". Since the var i is in scope of where you are calling "myfunction", by the time the  Interval timer expires, the value of i is actually beyond the end of your myparam array, so I'm surprised it would report anything meaningful. It should be sending "undefined" to myfunction.

Comment: Thank you so much! @Beginner I just incorporated what you said into my code and it works flawlessly now!!

Comment: @pacifier21 yes, I know my syntax was awful in the original, I was trying to simplify the actual code I have and I changed a few things