# Whats the need and use of nested functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nested-function

I understand what a nested function is, but I don't understand why we even need nested functions in the first place. Is there a problem that can only be solved by using nested functions in JavaScript. All the examples I see which create nested function, can be coded without creating a function inside a function and will result the same. So which problem requires creation of nested functions, and can only/efficiently be solved by using nested functions.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728278/what-is-a-practical-use-for-a-closure-in-javascript

Comment: @FabianLauer I'm waiting for someone to say nested functions are only useful when creating a closure.

Comment: privacy can only be achieved with nested functions, most module systems depend on closures too, to not pollute ther global namespace. Without closures you eiteher have to register everything somewhere in the global namespace, where every other script can access and modify it, or you have to pass stuff like the internal state as a argument to every public function of that class. So basically you don't have any internal state anymore, only public ones.

Answer (score 13):

The core importance of nested functions is scope generation. We need nested functions and scopes in JavaScript to achieve the following.

1. [Non-Polluted Global Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted)
2. [Modularization](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) of functionality
3. Encapsulate private internal workings of [modules](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)
4. Prevent collision of identifiers across different scripts
5. Smaller script sizes due to the fact that variables inside nested scopes qualify for [minification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)).
6. It speeds up the [Identifier Resolution Process](http://davidshariff.com/blog/javascript-scope-chain-and-closures/)

Here is a sample module that displays the power of encapsulation offered by function nesting and scopes:

```
var notificationService = (function ($, toastr, undefined) {
    var _externals = {},
        _jqExtend = $.extend;

    /*
     * Private Methods
     */
    function _showMessage(params) {
        params = params || {};
        toastr.remove();

        if (typeof (params.title) === "undefined")
            toastr[params.method](params.msg);
        else
            toastr[params.method](params.msg, params.title);
    }

    /*
     * Public Members
     */
    _externals.clear = function () {
        toastr.remove();
    };

    _externals.showError = function (params) {
        params = params || {};

        _jqExtend(params, {
            method: "error"
        });

        _showMessage(params);
    };

    _externals.showInfo = function (params) {
        params = params || {};

        _jqExtend(params, {
            method: "info"
        });

        _showMessage(params);
    };

    _externals.showSuccess = function (params) {
        params = params || {};

        _jqExtend(params, {
            method: "success"
        });

        _showMessage(params);
    };

    _externals.showWarning = function (params) {
        params = params || {};

        _jqExtend(params, {
            method: "warning"
        });

        _showMessage(params);
    };

    return _externals;
})(jQuery, toastr);
```

The code above gives us the power to control which things to expose. In this specific case all members attached to the _externals object are exposed to the global namespace via reference to notificationService object. Without using scoping, internal members (_jqExtend and _showMessage) would also be attached to the window object and increase the effort required by the browser to resolve identifier references.

Answer (score 4):

It's not about efficiency but about the paradigm. If you use the script paradigm you can just code away without worries. If you use the classical paradigm, you need to define classes but you don't need nested functions. Still, in scripting and classical, you MAY use nested functions if you want to.

Only if you switch to the functional paradigm, which is the actual "native" paradigm of javascript, you *NEED* nested functions in some cases.

As long as you do not use functional programming you'll not leverage all the power of javascript. This is an example of a factory that uses a *closure* that cannot be done otherwise (there are several other uses for nested functions, not just a closure):

```
function create(a, b)
{
  function compute()
  {
    return a + b;
  }

  return {
    "compute": compute
  };
}
```

The user code will do:

```
f = create(19, 73);
```

Without computing anything. Say, it takes a lot of time to compute this and you don't want to compute it unless necessary. You can now pass the function `f` to other code that is not yours (e.G. jQuery event handler code):

```
$("#id").on("click", function () { console.log(f.compute()); });
```

This `f` will be executed when you click on `#id`, but you cannot do anything about it. The arguments `a` and `b` are already embedded when `create()` was called.

This means that you can have *information hiding* and leverage *contextual scoping*. Imagine that the *creator* and the *user* are two different codebases not written by the same person. Or that `a` and `b` are secrets to be kept as such from the other codebase.

Look up the various words I sprinkled in the text above to learn more about functional programming.

> If you want to know why we can't do without, then look at [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) and [monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)), which are a fundamental parts of the functional paradigm. You need some mechanisms by which you can do these basic operations, otherwise the paradigm cannot be functional.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript variables can belong to the local or global scope.

Global variables can be made local (private) with closures.

functions in JS are like variables, so if may want to use nested functions to be for local use.

> Here's a good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295634/javascript-nested-function)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are several ways of doing a task in programming But among them we have to choose a method which is efficient and faster in terms of memory and execution time.When you need to switch from a main program to subroutine then time for context switch is more than just performing a inline task if size of subroutine is smaller..So overall its benificial if size smaller otherwise you always have a alternate path..Also a Nested function have the access to the scope "above" them.It will reduce the headache of passing a argument to function and reuse it somewhere else in the program..All above variables and functions are accessible to this Nested function and can update them..