# IIFEs as closures

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, iife

In the [You Don't Know Javascript](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch5.md) series, 1/3 of the way down IIFE's are described as not being closures themselves, but only if they're executed outside their lexical scope:

> Chapter 3 introduced the IIFE pattern. While it is often said that
>   IIFE (alone) is an example of observed closure, I would somewhat
>   disagree, by our definition above.
>
> This code "works", but it's not strictly an observation of closure.
>   Why? Because the function (which we named "IIFE" here) is not executed
>   outside its lexical scope. It's still invoked right there in the same
>   scope as it was declared (the enclosing/global scope that also holds
>   a). a is found via normal lexical scope look-up, not really via
>   closure.

```
var a = 2;

(function IIFE(){ // not actually a "closure"
    console.log( a ); 
})();
```

In this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728278/what-is-a-practical-use-for-a-closure-in-javascript), the following snippet was given as an example of a closure:

```
for (var i = 0; i < someVar.length; i++)
    (function (i) {
        window.setTimeout(function () { 
            alert("Value of i was "+i+" when this timer was set" )
        }, 10000);
    })(i);
```

I am trying to understand this in terms of the definition of closure (as defined in [this medium article](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-closure-b2f0d2152b36)):

> To use a closure, simply define a function inside another function and
>   expose it. To expose a function, return it or pass it to another
>   function.   ...
>
> The inner function will have access to the variables in the outer
>   function scope, even after the outer function has returned.

I understand that a closure is a "stateful function", and that it is

> a way to "remember" and continue to access a function's scope (its
>   variables) even once the function has finished running.

So in this example, I see that the loop's `i` is remembered when passed into the closing IIFE.

**My question is:**

Where is the "passing to another function or returning" portion happening? My guess is that the IIFE is able to remember the outer `i` for loop value at each iteration because the IIFE is passed to the window?

Basically, my understanding is that a closure is *defined* as remembering an outer scope's value after the Garbage collector cleans that outer scope up, and that the *usage* of it is to expose the closure by returning it and accessing it outside its lexical scope. Is this correct? So where is that "accessing it outside the lexical scope" happening?

Comment: A better example of an IIFE that's a closure would be `let plus3 = (x => y => x + y)(3);`. Here the variable `x` is closed over. When you call it with the value 3 it returns a function that takes another argument y and adds 3 to it.

Comment: I'm not sure a closure becomes not-a-closure simply based on when/where it is invoked...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I think the author the OP is quoting meant something to the effect of "when it doesn't actually close over anything of interest in the surrounding scope".

Comment: @growler the `window` has nothing to do with it, all the anonymous functions passed to `setTimeout` are closing over the variable `i` in the loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: @JaredSmith yes I understand that. But the question is, if the anonymous functions passed to `setTimeout` close over the variable `i`, why isn't that `i` preserved? The wrapping IIFE (`(function (i) { ... })(i)`) creates more closured scope which somehow preserves the `i` after the loop finishes. Is that because the wrapping `IIFE` is executed at a different scope?

Comment: In the `(function (i) { ... })(i)` example, the purpose of that IIFE is to create a local (argument) variable so that each of the `setTimeout` callbacks refer to a different, local variable named `i` instead of the same global `i`. The function passed into `setTimeout` clsoes over the `i` created by the argument named `i` in the surrounding IIFE.

Comment: @growler `i` *is* preserved. It *has to be*, because the `setTimeout` makes the execution asynchronous. Without the IIFE to create the closure, `i` will be whatever the value is when the callback is actually called, in this case it will be `someVar.length - 1` over and over again rather than incrementing values. Punch `for (var i=0; i<10; ++i) setTimeout(function() { console.log(i) })` in to the console.

Comment: @apsillers I think I've got it. Since it's an anonymous function, it's placed outside the event loop until the `for loop` finishes (at which point, `i` === `someVar.length-1`). When the event loop stack is clear, the `setTimeout` is executed and returns... without the `IIFE`, `setTimeout`'s anonymous function is still closing over `i`, but it's already after the event loop has finished. The `IIFE` is called for each iteration of `i` and creates a local variable of `i`'s value.

Comment: So with or without the `IIFE`, the `setTimeout`'s anonymous function still closes over `i`. We just want to close over the correct local `i` from the executed `IIFE`

Comment: @Growler yes that is correct. Sorry if I was unable to communicate that clearly, glad apsillers got it for you.

Comment: @JaredSmith makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in this example, I see that the loop's `i` is remembered when passed into the closing IIFE

No. The IIFE is only providing the scope for the `i` value to be remembered. As the quotes you cited state, the IIFE function is not a closure. The function expression that *uses* the `i` is the closure:

```
(function IIFE(i) {
    // this is the scope of i

    window.setTimeout(function closure() {
        // this function closes over i
        alert("Value of my local 'i' is still "+i+" even after 10 seconds");
    }, 10000);
})(0);
// ^ this is some arbitrary value passed to the IIFE - it could have been a loop variable
```

> Where is the "passing to another function or returning" portion happening?

It's the `closure` function being passed into `setTimeout`, which will call it back from a place where `i` would usually be no longer defined - if it wasn't a closure.

Comment: thank you for this. I already got it sorted out in the comments below my question :)