# Callback function cannot access variable within parent function's scope

Tags: javascript

In the below code, variable `text` is not accessible in the `findTextToDelete` function (it generates an error)

```js
array = ['a', 'b', 'removeThis', 'c'];
removeText("removeThis");

function removeText(text) {
    array.splice(array.findIndex(findTextToDelete),1);
}

function findTextToDelete(element) {
    return element === text;
}
```

I am able to get around this by creating a global variable 'globalText':

```js
var globalText = "";
array = ['a', 'b', 'removeThis', 'c'];
removeText("removeThis");

function removeText(text) {
    globalText = text;
    array.splice(array.findIndex(findTextToDelete),1);
}

function findTextToDelete(element) {
    return element === globalText;
}

console.log(array)
```

However I am trying to understand why the first method does not work.

It seems there must be a better way to do this. Is there a way to pass 'text' into the callback function?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728278/what-is-a-practical-use-for-a-closure-in-javascript) over `text` for finding the element.

```js
function removeText(text) {
    array.splice(array.findIndex(findTextToDelete(text)), 1);
}

function findTextToDelete(text) {
    return function (element) {
        return element === text;
    }
}

var array = ['a', 'b', 'removeThis', 'c'];

removeText("removeThis");
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you are confused with [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Callback function doesn't have caller's scope. So you can't access the variable `text` in `findTextToDelete`.

If you want to access the variable, pass it to the callback function as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Locals defined in one function are only available to other functions that are defined within the first function. The scope of locals defined in a function is limited to that function. This is generally known as [*lexical scoping*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1047491/67392). (Other languages have different rules, but lexical is common in imperative languages.)

So you need to define a function inside `removeText` to access `text`.

One way is to just use a function literal rather than a named function:

```
function removeText(text) {
    globalText = text;
    array.splice(array.findIndex(function (element) {
        return element === globalText;
    }, 1);
}
```

Another way is to forward the extra value:

```
function removeText(text) {
    globalText = text;
    array.splice(array.findIndex(function (el) { returnfindTextToDelete(el, text); }, 1);
}

function findTextToDelete(element, text) {
    return element === globalText;
}
```

(If you're not stuck with backward compatibility then arrow functions make both easier to write.)