# What is the exact use of closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

[closure](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) is hurting me in my every interviews.  finally I learned something about [closure](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp). But my question is what is the difference between these below snippets? Which scenarios should we use closures?

### Closure:

```js
function add(x) {
    return function(y) {
    return function(z) {
    return x + y + z;
    } 
    };
}

console.log(add(1)(2)(3))
```

Instead of closure, **Simply** we can pass three parameter into a single method.

```js
function add(x,y,z) {
   
    return x + y + z;
}

console.log(add(1,2,3))
```

So why I need to use closure?

Comment: That's very little to do with *closures*. They are used, yes, but a closure doesn't necessarily mean to structure your code like the first example. The topic you are after is "currying" and/or "partial application of functions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, there is no real difference in the output. However, let's make it even simpler:

```js
function add(a) {
  return function(b) {
    return a+b;
  }
}


console.log(add(1)(2));
```

```js
function add(a, b) {
  return a+b;
}

console.log(add(1, 2));
```

For simplicity, the function takes two parameters. One time you have to pass them both when invoking, the other you have to pass them one by one. Let's look at how that could be useful:

```js
function add(a) {
  return function(b) {
    return a+b;
  }
}

let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

//lets add the same number to all members of the array:
const numberToAdd = 5;

//traditionally
const newArray = []; //make a new array

for (let num of numbers) { //define a loop
  newArray.push(num + numberToAdd); //populate the array
}

console.log(newArray);

//functional
const mappedArray = numbers.map(num => num + numberToAdd); //using .map to handle everything
console.log(mappedArray);

//using the function we have
const betterMappedArray = numbers.map(add(numberToAdd));
console.log(betterMappedArray);
```

So, the functional approach via `.map` is shorter and easier but can be even further improved by passing a function. Without the `add` function you still pass a function, you define a new addition function *every time* you want to just add something to an array. If you want to add variable amounts, then without `add`, you have to create two new functions that fundamentally all do the same thing

```js
function add(a) {
  return function(b) {
    return a+b;
  }
}

let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];


console.log("using .map() with new functions");
console.log(
  numbers
    .map(num => num + 5)
    .map(num => num + 10)
);

console.log("using .map() with add()");
  
console.log(
  numbers
    .map(add(5))
    .map(add(10))
);
```

As you can see, put side-by-side it seems quite wasteful to make new functions every time. Even having the signature as `add(a, b)` so it takes two arguments means you would have to call `numbers.map(num => add(num, 5))` which does not improve anything.

Bear in mind that `add` is really simple - you might have a function that is more complex. Still, going with the simple example, let's re-write the example to show how it could be useful:

```js
function add(a) {
  return function(b) {
    return a+b;
  }
}

const shoppingCart = [
  {name: "item1", price: 1},
  {name: "item2", price: 2},
  {name: "item3", price: 3},
  {name: "item4", price: 4},
  {name: "item5", price: 5},
  {name: "item6", price: 6},
];

const applyHandlingTax = add(5);
const applyShippingTax = add(10);

const numbers = shoppingCart.map(item => item.price); //extract prices from the shopping cart

const finalPrices = numbers
  .map(applyHandlingTax)
  .map(applyShippingTax);

console.log(finalPrices);
```

It's a naive example with exaggerated numbers but it just serves to show what we can do here. This is functionally the same as the previous snippet but as you can see, we now have *business logic* with barely any changes.

- We've defined `applyHandlingTax` as adding `5`. We've also defined `applyShippingTax` to be adding `10`.
- Both of these are functions, so we can apply them via `.map` directly onto the result set we have, reducing the amount of code we have to write.
- The business rule is easy to understand, as you are writing pretty human readable code - you need very little knowledge of programming to understand `numbers.map(applyHandlingTax).map(applyShippingTax)` is applying shipping and handling tax to each of the numbers. And as a developer, it's clear that you are adding a shipping and a handling tax.
- If we are sure that `add` works correctly, then *by definition* anything deriving from it would also work - there is no need to test `applyShippingTax`. In fact, there is *nothing to test* - there is no body of the function, we haven't written any logic for it, we only use the result of a function for it.
- the only meaningful code we've written is for defining `add` and to extract the prices from the items. Even then, the latter can easily be abstracted in the same way that we've done with `add`, so we can apply it against *any* sort of result set

```js
function extract(name) {
  return function(item) {
    return item[name];
  }
}

const shoppingCart = [
  {name: "item1", price: 1},
  {name: "item2", price: 2},
  {name: "item3", price: 3},
  {name: "item4", price: 4},
  {name: "item5", price: 5},
  {name: "item6", price: 6},
];

const people = [
  {name: "Alice",  drives: "Audi"},
  {name: "Bob",    drives: "BMW"},
  {name: "Carol",  drives: "Citroen"},
  {name: "David",  drives: "Dodge"},
  {name: "Esther", drives: "EDAG"},
  {name: "Fred",   drives: "Ford"},
];

const prices = shoppingCart.map(extract('price'));
console.log(prices);

const names = people.map(extract('name'));
const cars = people.map(extract('drives'));
console.log(names);
console.log(cars);
```

Even with a pretty trivial example of `add` we can get pretty far. The particular style of how `add` is written is known as [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry_(programming_language)) - instead of taking **X** amount of parameters at once, the function returns *another* function that takes **X - 1** until it's satisfied.

Functions that work with other functions - either producing them (like `add` does), consuming them, or both are called [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function). If we use those and currying consistently we get into the territory of [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). Writing in a completely functional style is not a requirement to get benefit from these - as we saw with `add`, you can write a simple application without using lots of code even if we are applying business rules.

Answer (score 1):

That is a pretty synthetic and mostly useless example. In a nutshell, you need closures because Javascript uses a lot of callback based code, and you want to retain accessibility to the former scope in those callbacks:

```
function foo(bar) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert(bar);
    });
}
```

The closure mechanism here allows `alert(bar)` to still have access to `bar`, even though `foo` has already finished executing and all of its variables should have gone out of scope. That's what a *closure* is, it *closes over* the scope and keeps it available.

Answer (score 1):

This particular example shows a curried function to enable [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). It might not seem useful for a single function call, but also allows you to write

```js
function add(x) { return function(y) { return x + y; }; }

const add2 = add(2);
console.log(add2(1)); // 3
console.log(add2(40)); // 42
```

Sure, if the `add` function wasn't curried you could have used

```
function add2(y) {
  return add(2, y);
}
```

but that's unnecessarily verbose.

---

Of course, this highlights only a single use case of closures, there are [many many more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2728278/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

'add(1)(2)(3)' and 'add(1,2,3)' have same result. but I can do many things with the former one.
Let me give you an example.

```js
function add(x) {
    return function(y) {
    return function(z) {
    return x + y + z;
    } 
    };
}

const WELCOME_POINT = 10;
const VIP_POINT = 20;
function myPointCaculator(currentPoint, predicate) {
  if(typeof predicate === 'number')
    return currentPoint + predicate;
  else if(typeof predicate === 'function') {
    return currentPoint + predicate(WELCOME_POINT);
  } else {
    return currentPoint;
  }
}
  
const eventPoint = add(WELCOME_POINT)(VIP_POINT);
myPointCaculator(WELCOME_POINT, eventPoint);
```

'add(1,2,3)' is going to execute directly but 'add(1)(?)(?)' can be passed to function as parameter. That is different. This is about 'currying' and 'first order function'
First order function in javascript can make you code with functional programming.